# Append Image to Clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, image, charts, bitmapsource

I have third part control `Chart` which has `CopyToClipboard(size)` functionality. Same method returns `BitMapSource` as well.

So my need is: Append another `BitMapSource` to clipboard. How to acheive this functionality?.

Similarity between these two image could be same width and differ in height. I have to append one below another.

Comment: Are you trying to add two images to the clipboard? or append two images in the clipboard?

Comment: Either two images to clipboard or append, both will do...

Comment: The question is rather, what do you want to do with the data in the Clipboard. I suspect this is an XY problem.

Comment: @Akselk, Quite simple, Copy two images from two different chart instance and send it to clipboard as single image, later user will paste in powerpoint or word document.

Comment: Ah yes, an XY problem. You think you need to append another BitMapSource to the clipboard when you really need to insert two images into Office's clipboard. That's a different thing. Word uses a special kind of Clipboard, to enable multiple images and text, and paragraphs. Take a look into that instead, and re-ask your question "How do I insert two images into Word's clipboard?"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind saving the images to disk, this is the way to go:

```
string[] listOfFileNames = new string[]{@"C:\DSC00761.JPG",@"C:\DSC00758.JPG"};
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetData("FileDrop", listOfFileNames);
Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats().Dump();
```

Where listOfFileNames is replaced by the temporary names of the files. Clear the clipboard and delete the files when you exit your application.

Comment: Works for me (DOTNET 3.5), except for the .Dump() at the end.

Comment: Btw, MSWord pastes the images in reverse order.

Comment: The .Dump() is a LinqPad method. I must have used LinqPad to create the sample code. Check it out, it's worth it.